# How to count number of pixels for specific color from Image Using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I want to calculate the total number of pixels from a image for specific color witch will have all Sade of that specific color for example blue its will check all shade of blue and will return Total count of blue pixels

What is typed but its checking for blue not for shades of blue

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('rin_test/Images33.png')

black = 0
red = 0

for pixel in im.getdata():
    if pixel == (30,144,255): # if your image is RGB (if RGBA, (0, 0, 0, 255) or so
        blue += 1
print('blue=' + str(blue))
```

Sample Image for blue color
[image]

Comment: Make a mask of all shades of blue using a range of hues via cv2.inRange(). Then count the non-zero values in the mask.

Comment: can you specify the code for counting non-zero vales from masked image

Comment: See Numpy np.count_nonzero() at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a range of hues in HSV color space in Python/OpenCV to get a mask. Then count the number of non-zero values in the mask.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('blue_bag.png')

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

# create mask for blue color in hsv
# blue is 240 in range 0 to 360, so for opencv it would be 120
lower = (100,100,100)
upper = (160,255,255)
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# count non-zero pixels in mask
count=np.count_nonzero(mask)
print('count:', count)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('blue_bag_mask.png', mask)

# Display various images to see the steps
cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mask:

[image]

```
count: 34231
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
blue = sum(np.all(np.array(im.getdata()) == np.array([30,144,255]), axis=1))
```

Note that the blue value is more likely to be zero since there is a slight chance for the image to have an exact row that is equal to `[30,144,255]`

Comment: I don't want single shade np.array([30,144,255]) will give for for only single

Comment: how can i add lover and higher values for shade

Answer (score 0):

If you want different shades of blue, you have to specify a range of rgb values(that amount to different shades of blue) to be added to your variable)

For example :-

```
# If you want an array of the shades

blue = []
values = [<shades of blue>]
for pixel in im.getdata():
    for value in values:
        if pixel == value: 
            blue.append(value)
print('blue=' + str(blue))

# If you just want to add the number of times your shades appear

blue = 0
values = [<shades of blue>]
for pixel in im.getdata():
    for value in values:
        if pixel == value: 
            blue += 1
print('blue=' + str(blue))
```

Comment: how can I add lover and higher values for shade instead of this values = [<shades of blue>] mins can I specify range for shades

Comment: To do that, you would have to create a list or an array, probably like:-

color0 = list(np.random.choice(range(<shade val for r channel>), size=1))
color1 = list(np.random.choice(range(<shade val for g channel>), size=1))
color2 = list(np.random.choice(range(<shade val for b channel>), size=1))

and then join these together